# Win 10: Desktop.ini infotip/tooltip text formatting - line break

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop.ini

I'm trying to customize some folders in Windows 10 os using `Desktop.ini` text files. One thing I can't solve is how to make a line break in the infotip.

Current text file looks like this:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
ConfirmFileOp=0
NoSharing=1
IconFile=$path_to_icon
IconIndex=0
InfoTip=Line1 \n Line2
```

So the last line of the text document is not working as desired. It just doesn't recognize the \n symbol. I also tried replacing the standard \n new line symbol with unicode characters and some other similar methods and symbols, but it didn't work. It just recognizes it as a string no matter what is written there.

The only way I could achieve a line break was to add so many characters, that Win 10 would automatically start a new line.

Help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could define a string in a resource-only DLL:

```
InfoTip=@Your.dll,-12345
```

The negative number defines the resource ID of the string to use.

String resources in a DLL are not limited in the range of character codes, so this should in principle enable you to use line breaks (ASCII code 10).

To create such a resource-only DLL there are many free tools available, google for "windows resource editor".